Can I use a red tablecloth for Shabbos?
I’ve always heard that a Shabbos table should preferably be covered in white. Is this just a preference, or is there a reason (halachic or kabbalistic) to avoid using a different color?

We recently switched temporarily to a red table cloth, so +1

White is traditional for Yom Kippur

Beginning with the basics, the halacha is that one should use a table-cloth at this table due to the principle of "honoring Shabbos" (Chayei Adam, Shabbos 5:7). This is also the language of the Alter Rebbe in his Shulchan Aruch HaRav (262):

It is customary that the table be covered with a tablecloth throughout the entire Shabbos day as an expression of honoring the Shabbos.2 One should not deviate [from this custom].

The tablecloth should be left on during Shabbos, not only during dinner.
Back to the question what colour should be used. It seems to be a age-old minhag to use white as a colour of the table-cloth. This seems to be attributed to Rabbi Shimon Greenfeld in his Shailos U'Teshuvos Maharshag (Vol. 2, Siman 82, שו"ת מהרש"ג חלק ג) but I could not find that direct quote from that specific siman, though.

What color tablecloth is one to use? 1
The age old custom is to use a white tablecloth to cover the dining
table.
1: Drashos Mahariy Even, student of Rashba; See Maharshag 2/82


Your original source (chayei adam) does not say to have a tablecloth but rather to have a bottom-challah-cover
